# JPQL function encapsulating an aliased field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I had no problems with the following in Hibernate JPA

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN FETCH e.address AS a
WHERE a.state = :state
 AND e.middle = :middle
 AND trunc(a.birthdate) > :mindate
```

However,  eclipselink croaks syntax error on

```
trunc(a.birthdate) > :mindate
```

How do I encapsulate an alias-referenced field with an SQL function in eclipselink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the alias reference but the `trunc()` function - trunc is SQL not JPQL.

The answer to this question might help you:
    [SQL for NamedQuery in EclipseLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430555/sql-for-namedquery-in-eclipselink)